# How to add try , catch statement in my code to only take in an integer value?

Tags: java

Im creating a JOptionPane dialog box to take input from user to choose the type of cake they want to buy, but i only want to take in an integer value. I am very new to java programming and need some help using try, catch to only get an integer value.

I have created "Cakes[]" array to store and retrieve the flavor of cake, price of cake and the number of cakes left.

```
do {

    do {
        String userinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your choice of cake:"
        + "\n" + "1." + Cakes[0].getflavorofcake() + "(" + Cakes[0].getpriceofcake() + "cents" + ")" + "    no. of cakes available:" + Cakes[0].getnofcaksleft()
        + "\n" + "2." + Cakes[1].getflavorofcake() + "(" + Cakes[1].getpriceofcake() + "cents" + ")" + "      no. of cakes available:" + Cakes[1].getnofcaksleft()
        + "\n" + "3." + Cakes[2].getflavorofcake() + "(" + Cakes[2].getpriceofcake() + "cents" + ")" + "            no. of cakes available:" + Cakes[2].getnofcaksleft()
        + "\n" + "4." + Cakes[3].getflavorofcake() + "(" + Cakes[3].getpriceofcake() + "cents" + ")" + "        no. of cakes available:" + Cakes[3].getnofcaksleft()
        + "\n" + "5." + Cakes[4].getflavorofcake() + "(" + Cakes[4].getpriceofcake() + "cents" + ")" + "          no. of cakes available:" + Cakes[4].getnofcaksleft(), "mini cake shop", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

        choiceofcake = Integer.parseInt(userinput);

        showthatthereisnocakesleft(choiceofcake);//Method called to show user that the choiceofcake chosen is no longer available

    } while (Cakes[choiceofcake - 1].getnofcaksleft() < 1);

    if (choiceofcake > 5 || choiceofcake < 1) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input! Please enter in the range from  1 to 5", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
} while (choiceofcake > 5 || choiceofcake < 1);
```

Comment: yes where do i add the try , catch here ? its a bit confusing

Comment: and where do i add it? Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrap the

```
choiceofcake = Integer.parseInt(userinput);
```

with a try-catch

```
try {
   choiceofcake = Integer.parseInt(userinput);
   if (choiceofcake > 5 || choiceofcake < 1) {
        break;
   }
} catch (NumberFormatException ee) {
    ee.printStatckTrace ();
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the loop to continue, even in the event of a bad input, you may try something like:

```
do {
    String userinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your choice of cake:" +
        "\n" + "1." + Cakes[0].getflavorofcake() + "(" + Cakes[0].getpriceofcake() + "cents" + ")" + "    no. of cakes available:" + Cakes[0].getnofcaksleft() +
        "\n" + "2." + Cakes[1].getflavorofcake() + "(" + Cakes[1].getpriceofcake() + "cents" + ")" + "      no. of cakes available:" + Cakes[1].getnofcaksleft() +
        "\n" + "3." + Cakes[2].getflavorofcake() + "(" + Cakes[2].getpriceofcake() + "cents" + ")" + "            no. of cakes available:" + Cakes[2].getnofcaksleft() +
        "\n" + "4." + Cakes[3].getflavorofcake() + "(" + Cakes[3].getpriceofcake() + "cents" + ")" + "        no. of cakes available:" + Cakes[3].getnofcaksleft() +
        "\n" + "5." + Cakes[4].getflavorofcake() + "(" + Cakes[4].getpriceofcake() + "cents" + ")" + "          no. of cakes available:" + Cakes[4].getnofcaksleft(), "mini cake shop", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

    choiceofcake = Integer.parseInt(userinput);

    if (choiceofcake > 5 || choiceofcake < 1) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input! Please enter in the range from  1 to 5", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    else {
        showthatthereisnocakesleft(choiceofcake);
    }
} while (Cakes[choiceofcake - 1].getnofcaksleft() < 1);
```

If you want the loop to stop completely upon a bad input, then consider throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` when that occurs.

Answer (score 0):

you can add try-catch statement, so that if user inputted wrong value, you can show their error instead of terminating the program:

```
do {
        String userinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your choice of cake:" +
            "\n" + "1." + Cakes[0].getflavorofcake() + "(" + Cakes[0].getpriceofcake() + "cents" + ")" + "    no. of cakes available:" + Cakes[0].getnofcaksleft() +
            "\n" + "2." + Cakes[1].getflavorofcake() + "(" + Cakes[1].getpriceofcake() + "cents" + ")" + "      no. of cakes available:" + Cakes[1].getnofcaksleft() +
            "\n" + "3." + Cakes[2].getflavorofcake() + "(" + Cakes[2].getpriceofcake() + "cents" + ")" + "            no. of cakes available:" + Cakes[2].getnofcaksleft() +
            "\n" + "4." + Cakes[3].getflavorofcake() + "(" + Cakes[3].getpriceofcake() + "cents" + ")" + "        no. of cakes available:" + Cakes[3].getnofcaksleft() +
            "\n" + "5." + Cakes[4].getflavorofcake() + "(" + Cakes[4].getpriceofcake() + "cents" + ")" + "          no. of cakes available:" + Cakes[4].getnofcaksleft(), "mini cake shop", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);


            try{
                    choiceofcake = Integer.parseInt(userinput);
                    if (choiceofcake > 5 || choiceofcake < 1) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input! Please enter in the range from  1 to 5", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                    else {
                        showthatthereisnocakesleft(choiceofcake);
                    }
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                // e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(Exception e){
                // e.printStackTrace();
            }

    } while (Cakes[choiceofcake - 1].getnofcaksleft() < 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are new to Java, the idea of the try-catch is to surround a piece of code were an exception can occur. In your case "parseInt" can raise an exception if "userInput" can't be converted to a number. You can refer to the official documentation to discover which types of exceptions:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

You can also create and/or throw your own exceptions. For example, in this case, you can raise an IllegalArgumentException after checking that the "userInput" is outside of the required values with:

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException();
```

You can catch the exception somewhere and show then the message dialog with the alert.